# CodeIgniter Login Controller Form Authentication Not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, phpmyadmin, xampp

Hi I am encountering a strange error ,I have a small application having few pages for reports and entering logs ,the login authentication form is working perfectly fine on another host computer ,I have simply replicated the data to a new host computer ,the Login form gets refreshed after clicking on submit button ,I am not sure what is the reason behind I tried multiple ways to dig out the actual reason somehow I am failed here is my code data

Views/login.php
'''

```
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>ITS</title>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>frontend/css?family=Roboto:400,100,300,500">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>frontend/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>frontend/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>frontend/css/form-elements.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>frontend/css/style.css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Favicon and touch icons -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/ico/favicon.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">

</head>

<body>

    <!-- Top content -->
    <div class="top-content">
        
        <div class="inner-bg">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 text">
                        <h1><strong>ITS</strong></h1>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 form-box">
                        <div class="form-top">
                            <div class="form-top-left">
                                <h3>Login</h3>
                                <p>Enter your username and password to log on:</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-top-right">
                                <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-bottom">
                            <form action="<?php echo base_url('index.php/Login');?>" method="post" class="login-form">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="sr-only" for="form-username">Username</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username..." class="form-username form-control" id="form-username">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="sr-only" for="form-password">Password</label>
                                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password..." class="form-password form-control" id="form-password">
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign in!</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>


    <!-- Javascript -->
    <script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>frontend/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>frontend/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>frontend/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>frontend/scripts.js"></script>
    
    <!--[if lt IE 10]>
        <script src="assets/js/placeholder.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</body>
```

Controller/Login.php

```
<?php

class Login extends CI_Controller {
               
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->model('main_db');

        
        
        
    }   
    
    function index()
    {           
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'username', 'required|trim|xss_clean|max_length[100]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'required|trim|xss_clean|max_length[100]'); 
            
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<br /><span class="error">', '</span>');
    
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('login');
        }
        else 
        {
            
            $res=$this->main_db->get_table_where("users",array("username"=>set_value('username')));
            if($res)
            {
                $form_data = array(
                                'username' => set_value('username'),
                                'password' => set_value('password'),
                                );
                $res=$this->main_db->auth($form_data);  
                
                
                //print_r($res);                
                if ($res != "") 
                {
                    $uid = set_value('username');
                    $role = $res['role_id'];
                    $user_region= $res['region'];
                    $parameters['id']=$role;
                    $urole=$this->main_db->get_table_where('user_role',$parameters);
                    
                    $con1 =$this->main_db->get_table_data('configuration');
                    $org_name = $con1[0]->Organization_Name;
                    $org_address = $con1[0]->Organization_Address;
                    $org_phone = $con1[0]->Organization_Phone;
                    
                    
                    $ur = $urole[0]->role;
                    
                    
                    $this->session->set_userdata('username', set_value('username'));
                    $this->session->set_userdata('user_role', $ur);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('user_region', $user_region);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('org_name', $org_name);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('org_address', $org_address);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('org_phone', $org_phone);
                    
                    redirect('/mainpage/callregister');
    
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    $data["error"]="Password is incorrect.";
                    $this->load->view('login',$data);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $data["error"]="Username doesnot exist.";
                $this->load->view('login',$data);
            }
            
            
            
            
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Model/main_db.php

```
<?php
class Main_db extends CI_Model {

    var $debug = 1;
    var $user_region="";
    var $urole ="";

    function __construct()
    {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->library('custom_library');
        $this->user_region =$this->session->userdata("user_region");
        $this->urole =$this->session->userdata("user_role");
    }
    

    function Get_Row($qu,$parameters=array())
    {
        $dbquery = $this->db->query($qu, $parameters); 
        $ret = $dbquery->row_array();
        return $ret;        
    }
    
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////
    
    
    function auth($formdata)
    {
        $uid = $formdata['username'];
        $pwd = $formdata['password'];   
        $qu="select * from users where username=? and password=?";
        $parameters = array($uid, $pwd);
        $ret2 = $this->Get_Row($qu,$parameters);    
        if (count($ret2) > 0)
        {
            $ret=$ret2;
        }
        else
        {
            $ret="";
        
        }
        return $ret;        
    }
    
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    
    function get_table_data($table)
    {
        $query = $this->db->get($table);
        $res=$query->result();
        return $res;
    }
    
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    
    function get_table_where($table,$parameters=array())
    {
        $query = $this->db->get_where($table,$parameters);
        $res=$query->result();
        return $res;
    }
    
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    
    
    
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    
    function insert_table($table,$data)
    {
        return $this->db->insert($table,$data); 
    }
    

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    
    function update_table_where($table,$data=array(),$parameters=array())
    {
        $this->db->where($parameters);
        $this->db->update($table, $data);
        return $this->db->affected_rows();      
    }
    

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    function get_paginited_data($table, $start,$limit)
    {
          $query = $this->db->get($table, $limit, $start);
          $res=$query->result();
          return $res;
    }
    
    function get_paginited_where($table,$param=array(), $start,$limit)
    {

        $query = $this->db->get_where($table,$param, $limit, $start);
        //echo $this->db->last_query(); 
        $res=$query->result();
        return $res;
    }
    
    function get_role_menus($role)
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM role_permissions a inner join modules b on a.module_id=b.module_id and a.role='$role'";
        $query=$this->db->query($query);
        $res=$query->result();
        return $res;
    }
    
    
    function get_submodules($parent_id,$role)
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM submodules_permissions a inner join sub_modules b on a.module_id=b.module_id and a.role='$role' and a.parent_id='$parent_id' order by b.visible_name";
        $query=$this->db->query($query);
        $res=$query->result();
        return $res;
    }
    
    function get_menu_details($id,$child)
    {
        if($child==0)
        {
            $table="modules";
        }
        else
        {
            $table="sub_modules";
        }
        $qu="Select * from $table where module_id='$id'";
        $query=$this->db->query($qu);
        $r=$query->result();    
        return $r[0];
    }
    
    function count_childs($parent_id)
    {
        $qu="select count(*) as total from sub_modules where parent_id='$parent_id'";
        $query=$this->db->query($qu);
        $r=$query->result();    
        return $r[0]->total;
        
    }
    
    function get_child_menus($parent_id)
    {
        $qu="Select * from sub_modules where parent_id='$parent_id'";
        $query=$this->db->query($qu);
        $r=$query->result();    
        return $r;
    }
    
    function check_menu_permissions($id,$role,$child)
    {
        if($child==0)
        {
            $table="role_permissions";
        }
        else
        {
            $table="submodules_permissions";
        }
        $qu="Select count(*) as total from $table where module_id='$id' and role='$role'";

        $query=$this->db->query($qu);
        $r=$query->result();    
        return $r;
    }
    
    function delete_user_modules($role)
    {
        $qu="delete from role_permissions where role='$role'";
        $query=$this->db->query($qu);   
        return $query;
    }
    
    function delete_user_submodules($role)
    {
        $qu="delete from submodules_permissions where role='$role'";
        $query=$this->db->query($qu);
        return $query;
    }
    
    function add_module_permission($module_id,$role)
    {
        $res=$this->insert_table("role_permissions",array("role"=>$role,"module_id"=>$module_id));
        return $res;
    }
    
    function add_submodule_permission($module_id,$role,$parent_id)
    {
        $res=$this->insert_table("submodules_permissions",array("role"=>$role,"module_id"=>$module_id,"parent_id"=>$parent_id));
        return $res;
    }

    function debug_log($message)
    {
    $fp = fopen ("frontend/debug.log","a+");

    
    $date =  date("d-m-Y H:i:s");
    $log = $date ."\t ".$message."\n";
    
    fwrite($fp,$log);
    fclose($fp);
    
    
    ///////////////////
    if(file_exists("../frontend/debug.log"))
    {
    $fp3 = fopen ("../frontend/debug.log");

    $date =  date("d-m-Y H:i:s");
    $log = $date ."\t ".$message."\n";
    
    fwrite($fp3,$log);
    fclose($fp3);
    }
    }
    
    
    //////////////////////////////
    
    function daily_report($dfrom,$dto)
    {
    
    
    #$query = "SELECT * from callregister where current_date >='$dfrom' and current_date <='$dto' ";
    
    $query = "SELECT * from callregister where cdate >='$dfrom' and cdate <='$dto' ";
    #echo $query;
        $query=$this->db->query($query);
        $res=$query->result();
        
    
        return $res;    
    }
    /////adeel function//////
    
    
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////adeel////////////
    function summary_rep($month,$year)
    {
    $query="SELECT cdate,COUNT(*) as total FROM callregister WHERE  MONTH(cdate)='$month' AND YEAR(cdate)='$year' GROUP BY cdate ";
    $query=$this->db->query($query);
        $res=$query->result();
        
    
        return $res;    
    
    }
    
    
    /////////////call register pending tasks//////////////
    
    function pending_report($dfrom,$dto)
    {
    
    
    #$query = "SELECT * from pending where current_date >='$dfrom' and current_date <='$dto' ";
    
    $query = "SELECT * from pending where cdate >='$dfrom' and cdate <='$dto' ";
    #echo $query;
        $query=$this->db->query($query);
        $res=$query->result();
        
        return $res;    
    }
    
    


///////////////////////////////
    
    

}
?>
```

database.php

```
hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'callregister',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
```

Comment: what is your main problem??

Comment: what is a "host computer"? a localhost server or a production server or something else?

Comment: What error messages are you getting? What errors are being logged? There's a lot of info missing before we can take a stab at your issue

Comment: @KUMAR Hi the main problem is it does not proceeds further to user authentication and redirect user to main page after authentication, neither it displays any error, after enter user id and password either correct or incorrect it doesnot act it simply reloads the login page again.

Comment: @Vickel It is a desktop computer

Comment: @JavierLarroulet The main issue is I don't get any error at all ,it simply reloads the same login page when I click on submit button after entering user id and password.